# Why does Safari make netflix screenshots black?

Tags: macos, safari

What legal agreement or other reason does Apple have that makes them want to stop users from being able to screenshot netflix in Safari.app?

Comment: *WHY* Apple does anything is speculation because Apple does not tell anyone why they do things. Opinion based questions/answers are officially off topic here.

Comment: It’s called DRM.  Even hardware like HDMI devices cause this to happen if you try to capture protected content

Comment: @Allan oh yeah good point. Now that you've reminded me, I remember that I couldn't play Netflix on Safari through HDMI to a bigscreen monitor. What a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DRM is handled at the **source**; there is no contract or agreement per se with Netflix to prevent screen captured.

Netflix uses Google’s [WideVine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widevine).  Apple has [FairPlay](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/). Microsoft offers Azure Media Services DRM so that anyone who hosts with them can protect their content. AWS, likewise has a similar offering.

The Content server encrypts the transmission stream at the source. Your player (running on macOS) decrypts the stream.  Screen Capture can’t decoded this video stream.  Your [Apple device and macOS actually supports *hardware* based DRM](https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/blog/preventing-screen-capture-with-drm.html):

> Apple FairPlay only offers hardware DRM in two flavours: baseline for HD content and main for UHD HDR content.
>
> Most devices and browsers those days can support *hardware* DRM, including:
>
> - Chrome for Android
> - **Safari for macOS, iOS or iPadOS**
> - WebViews for Android and iOS
> - Smart TV
> - Video game consoles

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

Apple has a vested interested in protecting its own digital content so they have an added motivation to support and implement other DRM technologies.  In addition, [HDCP (High Bandwidth Copy Protection)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) is a technology licensed by Intel.  It is not far fetched that the license agreement Apple entered into specifies that it must protect against circumvention like screen captures.

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: Why does Apple's interest in protecting its own digital content (which content btw?) mean that they are also motivated to support Netflix's DRM?

Comment: @theonlygusti sources are supplied. See links.  As for your second question, it’s the doctrine of reciprocity.  Typically used for treaties, but tech companies engage in this behavior as well

Comment: I meant when you said "The DRM is handled at the **source**", what does that mean?

Comment: It means it’s encrypted at the streaming server of the content delivery network or on the DVD if you play locally.

Comment: Surely the screenshot tool doesnt have to decode the stream? Bc all the graphical information is already there being rendered on the monitor. Why isnt the screenshot tool just capturing that information? How can there be any difference between how screenshot behaves and how built-in output behaves?

Comment: Think of screen capture as you trying to put a DVR with no decoding between your set top box (satellite, cable, Roku…) and your TV. you’ll get nothing…just like the scenario you described in your comment earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Netflix uses DRM to protect its content in Safari. Because Safari offers this DRM, Netflix allows higher-quality playback.

In Edge & Safari, Netflix playback allows 4K playback. In Chrome & Firefox, they do not.

Comment: Do you know how web developers can enable this kind of thing on their site?